# How to send Notification/message to iOS device using FCM through Java(Spring Boot)?

Tags: ios, spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the functionality to send Notifications to Android Using com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender (generated device token using FCM in front-end).
But I need to send the notification to iOS devices as well,so how can I configure or change the below code done for Android to send notifications to iOS?

```
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("message", message.toString());
                map.put("badge", Integer.toString(badgeCount));
                map.put("messageId", Integer.toString(emergencyMessage.getMessageId()));
                map.put("issuedDateStr",
                        (emergencyMessage.getIssuedDateStr() != null) ? emergencyMessage.getIssuedDateStr() : "");
                map.put("title", pjmProperties.getProperty(APP_TITLE));
                map.put("soundname", "default");
                map.put("notId", Integer.toString(RandomUtils.nextInt(50001, 75000)));

                Message messageObj = new Message.Builder().delayWhileIdle(false).setData(map).build();
                sender.send(messageObj, deviceData.getToken(), 1);
```

How should I write code to send notifications to iOS devices using FCM/GCM?(instead of sending through APNS)

Answer (score 2):

To send notification for multiple device ids that may be Android or IOS.

You can use MulticastMessage in fireBase.

```
                    MulticastMessage multiCast = MulticastMessage.builder()
                        .putAllData(new HashMap<String, String>())
                        .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder().build())
                        .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder().build())
                        .addAllTokens(Arrays.asList("token1","token2"))
                        .build();
```

For reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message